# How to efficiently code a darkmode switch for a webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I was attempting to design a dark-mode switch for a webpage, and I am not sure if I implemented it in the most efficient manner. I basically created a extra copy (the files ending in "2") for each of the files for each section of the webpage, and changed the color attributes in the functions for those copies. I would then return either the original functions if the dark-mode status was not triggered or return the slightly modified ones if it was. I was wondering if there was a better method of creating a dark-mode switch rather than the brute-force approach I used. The Landing() function was inspired by https://medium.com/heuristics/react-dark-mode-switch-in-material-ui-dashboard-82fcf1cded66.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import Header from '../Landing Page/components/Header/Header';
import Header2 from '../Landing Page/components/Header/Header2';
import StickyHeader from '../Landing Page/components/Header/StickyHeader';

import ProductSection from '../Landing Page/components/Product/ProductSection';
import ProductSection2 from '../Landing Page/components/Product/ProductSection2';
import HardwareSection from '../Landing Page/components/HardwareSection/HardwareSection';
import HardwareSection2 from '../Landing Page/components/HardwareSection/HardwareSection2';
import DashboardSection from '../Landing Page/components/DashboardSection/DashboardSection';
import DashboardSection2 from '../Landing Page/components/DashboardSection/DashboardSection2';
import MarketplaceSection from '../Landing Page/components/MarketplaceSection/MarketplaceSection';
import MarketplaceSection2 from '../Landing Page/components/MarketplaceSection/MarketplaceSection2';
import CustomModelSection from '../Landing Page/components/CustomModelSection/CustomModelSection';
import CustomModelSection2 from '../Landing Page/components/CustomModelSection/CustomModelSection2';
import CommunicationSection from '../Landing Page/components/CommunicationSection/CommunicationSection';
import CommunicationSection2 from '../Landing Page/components/CommunicationSection/CommunicationSection2';
import TableSection from '../Landing Page/components/TableSection/TableSection';
import TableSection2 from '../Landing Page/components/TableSection/TableSection2';
import PartnerSection from '../Landing Page/components/PartnerSection/PartnerSection';
import PartnerSection2 from '../Landing Page/components/PartnerSection/PartnerSection2';

import GetStarted from '../Landing Page/components/Bottom/GetStarted';
import GetStarted2 from '../Landing Page/components/Bottom/GetStarted2';
import Footer from '../Landing Page/components/Bottom/Footer';
import Footer2 from '../Landing Page/components/Bottom/Footer2';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    minHeight: '100vh',
    backgroundImage: "url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2180654.jpg')",
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: 'contain',
  },
  dark: {
    minHeight: '100vh',
    backgroundImage: "url('https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1685406.jpg')",
    backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    backgroundSize: 'contain',
  },
}));

export default function Landing() {
  const [darkPage, setDarkPage] = React.useState(false);
  const scheme = darkPage ? 'dark' : 'light';
  const darkScheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: scheme,
    },
  });
  const handleChange = () => {
    setDarkPage(!darkPage);
  };

  const classes = useStyles();

  if (!darkPage) {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={darkScheme}>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Header />
          <Switch checked={darkPage} onChange={handleChange} />
          <StickyHeader />
          <ProductSection />
          <HardwareSection />
          <DashboardSection />
          <MarketplaceSection />
          <CustomModelSection />
          <CommunicationSection />
          <TableSection />
          <PartnerSection />
          <GetStarted />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  } else if (darkPage) {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={darkScheme}>
        <div className={classes.dark}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Header2 />
          <Switch checked={darkPage} onChange={handleChange} />
          <StickyHeader />
          <ProductSection2 />
          <HardwareSection2 />
          <DashboardSection2 />
          <MarketplaceSection2 />
          <CustomModelSection2 />
          <CommunicationSection2 />
          <TableSection2 />
          <PartnerSection2 />
          <GetStarted2 />
          <Footer2 />
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't use react, but looking at your code, i would keep the classes in two different "theme" folders with identical filenames in each foldeer.  You would just need to modify the path to point to the dark mode when appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're super close actually. The better way to do this is to rely on that ThemeProvider you've created. That provider can propagate the active theme (in your case either 'dark' or 'light') to other components in the app. Those components can then adjust their styles accordingly. The React Context documentation actually has a perfect example for this (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#examples). It will show you how to create a themed button. You can apply this same strategy to your other app components.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, apologies for the very delayed response.